# c++ Copy a binary tree

Tags: c++

If I use this to copy a binary tree

```
BTNode<ElemType>* BinaryTree<ElemType>::_Copy( BTNode<ElemType>* T){ 
    if (T == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    BTNode<ElemType> *p;
    p = new BTNode<ElemType>;
    p->data = T->data;
    p->lchild = _Copy(T->lchild);
    p->rchild = _Copy(T->rchild);
    return p; 
}
```

and set overload function for `=` operator like this:

```
BinaryTree& operator=(const BinaryTree &rhs){
    if (&rhs == this){
        return *this;
    }
    _Destroy (m_root);
    m_root = _Copy ( rhs.m_root);
    return *this;
}
```

then if I have two treetype element `tree_1` and `tree_2`.

When I do

```
tree_2 = tree_1;
```

I copy all the element from `tree_1` to `tree_2`.
And at this time, I add a new node to `tree_2`. The `tree_1` will also change.
How can I set a new recursive copy function that makes `tree_1` remains the same and only change the structure of `tree_2`?

Comment: Why are you defining an `_Copy` function instead of defining a copy constructor? Generally, if you define an assignment operator, you should also be defining a copy constructor. Also, when you need to define deep copy/assignment semantics you should do so for each type involved. Also, this code is full of memory leaks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**you Overide only the Node Element BTNode = operator**

thats way its work for the root copy 
when you copy the trees [tree_2 = tree_1;]

you are using the defult copy ctor that c++ provide
that use bitwise copy(deep copy)
you need to create a copy ctor 
for the tree that use foreach node 
the" =" operator you allreay implement

```
node  *Cpy( root ) { 

   if (root == NULL ) : return root;

   node *temp = new node();
   temp->data = root-> data;    

   temp->left = Cpy( root -> left);   

   temp->right = Cpy(root -> right);  

   return temp;
}
```

Comment: You should try to improve the english in your answer a bit.

Comment: At least use a `shared_ptr` or something. This is going to leak like crazy. Also the default copy constructor is not a deep copy.

Comment: i just try to help